# YUI framework draws a lines and remove the previous line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yui

I want to draw a line when clicking the mouse, and remove the previous line. This is the link from jsfiddle.net and the link is [there](http://jsfiddle.net/s9b67qc9/10/).

In my code, I realize that draw a line when clicking the mouse. But can not remove the previous line. I want to remove the previous line. Could someone helps me? Thanks a lot!

This is YUI code:

```
YUI().use('event', 'node', 'graphics', function (Y) {
var mygraphic = new Y.Graphic({
    render: "#play"
});

Y.one('#play').on('click', function (e) {
    var bob = mygraphic.addShape({
        type: "path",
        stroke: {
            weight: 4,
            color: "#00dd00"
        },
        fill: {
            type: "linear",
            stops: [{
                color: "#cc0000",
                opacity: 1,
                offset: 0
            }, {
                color: "#00cc00",
                opacity: 0.3,
                offset: 0.8
            }]
        }
    });
    if (bob) {
        bob.moveTo(100, 100);
        bob.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        bob.end();
        bob.closePath();
        //mygraphic.removeShape(bob);
    }
});

});
```

This is html and css code:

```
<div id="play"></div>

#play {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the previously drawn line so you can remove it on subsequent clicks.  I've updated your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s9b67qc9/11/ but the idea is to use a variable defined in the outer scope (ie the scope of the YUI.use() callback, rather than the scope of the 'click' callback).  This gets set to `bob`, and `oldBob` is then removed from the Graphic.

So now you have:

```
var mygraphic = new Y.Graphic({
        render: "#play"
    }),
    oldBob;
```

and in the event listener:

```
if (bob) {
    bob.moveTo(100, 100);
    bob.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    bob.end();
    bob.closePath();

    if (oldBob) {
        mygraphic.removeShape(oldBob);
    }
    oldBob = bob;
}
```